# Error a actualizar un registro de una tabla en SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Hola estimados colegas me pueden ayudar estoy usando SQLserver 2012 y al ejecutar el scrip me muestra este error
les dejo el scrip.

```
 UPDATE Maestro
SET
    id_es='CIE_CU',
    Estado = 'CIE_CU'
WHERE expediente    IN('0000002714','0000002715')
```

no me actualiza y me manda este mensaje

[image: mensaje al ejectucar el scrip anterior]

***Mens. 3609, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 1
La transacción terminó en el desencadenador. Se anuló el lote.***

Nota: [image: Lista de trigger]

gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Necesitamos ver el desencadenador (trigger) de la tabla Maestro.

Comment: gracias por tu comentario adjunte imagen de lo que creo que es lo que me estas solicitando

Comment: Ahí solo muestra que la tabla maestro tiene 2 triggers. Necesitamos ver su definición. Y no dupliques la pregunta.